# Polynomials converging uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show for each of the domains (I), if there exists a sequence of polynomials converges to $f$ where $f(x) = x \sin(1/x) $ if $x>0$ and $0$ if $x=0$.

(a)$I = (0,1]$

(b)$I = [1, \infty)$

Here's what I think: I think for both cases, there isn't any. for case (b): for any sequence of polynomials $\{P_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ we have $\| P_n -f \|_{sup} \geq \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}|P_n(x) - f(x)| = \infty \nrightarrow0$, so $P_n$ does not converge uniformly on R. **Is this correct?**

and for case (a): It's the same format but I think I have to consider $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}|P_n(x)-f(x)| $. I'm stuck here, I don't know how to show it $\nrightarrow0$.

Comment: You ask "if a sequence... where $f(x)=...$ " and give some domains $I$ but there is not a question asked about this situation.

Comment: Oh, edited. I meant show there exists a sequence of polynomials...

Comment: Do you mean "for each of the domains, does there exist..."? [That wording would be clearer (to me) since as it is it looks like "if there exists.." is one of the assumptions.]

Answer (score 1):

For case (a), your function is continuous on $[0,1]$ and therefore you can use the Weierstrass approximation theorem in order to prove that there is such a sequence of polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

On $[0,1]$, your $f$ is continuous. So it is a uniform limit of polynomials. The same sequence of polynomials will work on $(0,1]$.

On $[1,\infty)$, any polynomial is unbounded, while your function is bounded. So there cannot be uniform convergence.